# Typescript - Type 'String' Can't Be Used To Index - React Dynamic Component Name Map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I've got the following working and I'm trying to convert it to Typescript but whilst I somewhat understand the error, I'm not sure how to go about actually fixing it.

I am currently allowing a component to have a prop of "icon" which is a string and this string is then translating to a component name to be loaded.

**icons/index.ts**

```
import { BellIcon } from "./BellIcon";

export const iconMap = {
  BellIcon
};
```

**iconButton.tsx**

```
import { iconMap } from "./icons";

type IconButtonProps = {
  icon: string;
  label?: string;
  direction?: string;
  onClick: () => void;
};
```

The offending line:

```
const IconElement = iconMap[icon];
```

This is what I get as the two errors:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ BellIcon: (props: any) => Element; }'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ BellIcon: (props: any) => Element; }'.ts(7053)
```

Further down the page then for context I am calling the following to get the dynamic component loaded:

```
<IconElement />
```

I've tried setting various types but can't find anything that solves the problem, was more trying to guess and I'd actually like to understand the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the type of the `icon` prop to only accept keys of the `iconMap` object.

```js
import { iconMap } from "./icons";

type IconButtonProps = {
  icon: keyof typeof iconMap;
  label?: string;
  direction?: string;
  onClick: () => void;
};
```

Comment: Kicking myself now at how easy/obvious that actually was!

Answer (score 3):

@emeraldsanto's answer is correct, but to add some more detail:

When you define an object like

```
const MyMap = {
  foo: 'bar'
};
```

Typescript takes a strict approach w/r/t keys and infers the type as

```
{
  foo: string;
}
```

This means that only the key `"foo"` is accepted as a valid property in this map. You can override this by setting the type explicitly:

```
const MyMap: {[key: string]: string} = {
  foo: 'bar'
};
```

or

```
const MyMap: Record<string, string> = {
  foo: 'bar'
};
```

(These have some subtle differences, but in this case will work the same.) Now TS knows that any string is a valid key for `MyMap`.

To go stricter, you can use `as const` to indicate that your object should be treated as frozen:

```
const MyMap = {
  foo: 'bar'
} as const;
```

Now TS infers the type in the strictest way:

```
{
  readonly foo: 'bar'
};
```

This can be beneficial, as now `MyMap.foo` can be used in contexts that only accept `"bar"`, not any string, and TS will give you an error if you try to compare to something it knows is incorrect, like `if (MyMap.foo === "spam")`.